# RxJs retry on "outer" observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, retry-logic

I have a Component Store that is calling an api endpoint. Sometimes, the payload can become quite lengthy and the response fails because the url is too long. There's a lot of different scenarios that I don't want to worry about, so what I'm trying to do is use RxJs `retry` to execute the Api call again, but without the massive payload the second time.

However, the only time I can get `retry` to actually work is when it is directly after the api call. But, in order to pick up the "updated" variable, I need to to retry the "outer" observable.

```
request$.pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
          this._store.select((state) => state.bigPayload),
          this._store.select((state) => state.somethingElse)
        ),
        switchMap(([{ request }, bigPayload, somethingElse]) => {
          return this._service
            .callApi(
              bigPayload
            )
            .pipe(
              tap({
                error: (err) => {
                  console.log('err1', err); // happens
                  // clear the state
                  this._store.dispatch(Action.resetBigPayload());
                  return throwError(() => err);
                },
                next: (resp) => {
                  // success stuff
                }
              }),
              // retry(1), // works here
            );
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('err2', err); // happens
          return throwError(() => err);
        }),
        retry(1), // doesn't work here where I need it?
      )
```

I think I may be misunderstanding what is being retried maybe? I'd expect the entire ovservable to retrigger, but nothing seems to happen. Works fine with the "inner" retry, but I can't reset/clear my payload before the retry.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution, but the inner `retry` works, because the inner observable had an error. I see, that you rethrow the error in order to catch it in the outer observable, but this isn't the same, as the outer observable had an error. Maybe you could use the `retryConfig` interface to do some extra logic before retrying the request.

Comment: That is my conclusion as well. It's a mystery why the retry doesn't get picked up, especially when the `catchError` does.

Answer (score 1):

Catching errors and retrying is actually kinda mysterious at first.

The reason the inner retry works is because there is only `tap({error: ...})` there. `tap` operator does nothing at all to the observable, so the `return throwError` has no effect at all.

But in the outer observable, you call `catchError` and return `throwError` in there. What returning from `catchError` does is that it replaces the original obaservable up to (including) the `catchError` operator by the observable returned from the `catchError` callback.

You are returning `throwError` observable, that only throws. Then you `retry` on that observable, which means you only retry the throwing.

If you place the `retry` before the `catchError` or replace the `catchError` by `tap({error: ...})`, then the whole outer observable be retried.

This is similar to what I describe in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77108443/switchmap-in-catcherror-executes-only-the-first-time/77111125#77111125).