# switchMap in catchError executes only the first time

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a `Redux` store with some rxjs operators in Angular. In it, I have an `Observable` that fetches data from a server.

The `Observable` has a `catchError`. The first `console.log` in this `catchError` logs at all times. The second `console.log` logs only the first time the component is rendered. Every subsequent error is being ignored by the code in the `switchMap` which in turn does not execute. Why is that?

```js
catchError(error => {
  console.log("this line is logged each time")
  return this.someServiceApi.getSomeServerValue().pipe(
    tap(t => console.log("this line is logged only the first time. The call to getSomeServerValue is always being made")),
    switchMap(someServerValue => {
       console.log("this line is logged only the first time. The call to getSomeServerValue is always being made")
    })
  )
})
```

`getSomeServerValue` is only an observable that returns a boolean value.

Comment: ts won't allow you to compile this code as you have to return observable or an array or maybe promise from the switchMap

Comment: There's nothing wrong on the code you have shared. This can only happen if 1. `getSomeServerValue()` doesn't emit (although why wouldn't it?) or if 2. the problem is in the retry logic: It unsubscribes before `getSomeServerValue()` had the chance for re-emitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you provided very little code, so my answer can only be generic:

The `catchError` callback will only be called on the first error. Whatever happens in the original observable before `catchError` will not be subscribed to by any operator or `.subcribe()` call after it. The observable before and including `catchError` will be replaced by the observable that your return from the `catchError` callback. Therefore the `catchError` will never be called again.

If you want to continue listening on the original observable inlcuding `catchError` operator, you can use the second parameter passed into the `catchError` callback:

```
catchError((error, resume$) => {
  console.log("this line is logged each time")
  return this.someServiceApi.getSomeServerValue().pipe(
    // store the value somewhere or do whatever you like with it
    tap(value => dispatcher.dispatch(valueLoaded(value)),
    switchMap(() => {
       // resume to the original observable
       return resume$
    })
  )
})
```

Just note, that the original `catchError` will *not* catch errors from the `getSomeServerValue()` call. You could for example resume also to the original observable if an error happens in the `getSomeServerValue()` observable:

```
catchError((error, resume$) => {
  console.log("this line is logged each time")
  return this.someServiceApi.getSomeServerValue().pipe(
    // store the value somewhere or do whatever you like with it
    tap(value => dispatcher.dispatch(valueLoaded(value)),
    catchError(() => resume$),
    switchMap(()=> {
       // resume to the original observable
       return resume$
    })
  )
})
```

You might wanna add some delay though if the original observable emits every time it is subscribed to ([cold observable](https://luukgruijs.medium.com/understanding-hot-vs-cold-observables-62d04cf92e03)), because it will emit immediately after an error happens in `getSomeServerValue()`. If that emission ends up in error again, it will loop indefinitely.